# sendmail: Not running with correct effective GID. Is sendmail binary setgid mailtrap?

Tags: apache, cmd, cpanel, whm

I am having a problem sending contact forms through mail(), when looking at the server log I'm getting the following error:

```
sendmail: Not running with correct effective GID.  Is sendmail binary setgid mailtrap?
```

I've already searched for an answer to this which suggested to set the permissions and owner group which are already set to their suggestions.

However I ran the cmd they suggested and i am now getting this error.

```
cwd=/home/spiralst/public_html 3 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have WHM access or just cPanel access?

Comment: I have WHM access. I was able to get the error back `sendmail: Not running with correct effective GID.  Is sendmail binary setgid mailtrap?` as it that seemed more documented. But i have tried the comman answer of running these commands `chown root:mailtrap /usr/sbin/sendmail` and `chmod 2755 /usr/sbin/sendmail`

Comment: Did you check this? https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/redirecting-autoresponder-from-usr-sbin-sendmail.563541/

Comment: I will give it a go and let you know if i have any luck! Out of interest does sendmail effect emails being send from the server as we have few email account setup on there?

Comment: Basically on WHM the default email program is exim not sendmail

Comment: Hi Bogdan, thanks for the help, that link put me on the right trail. Turns out although the error said usr/sbin/sendmail was the file with the error it turns out the error was in with usr/sbin/exim which needed this command to be ran. `chmod +s /usr/sbin/exim`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this error I checked the mail queue which showed all emails and contact form entries were queuing to be sent.

After some research I found a helpful post which suggested running `chmod +s /usr/sbin/exim` which appeared to correct this issue.